# How to use thenComparing in java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I have a map with strings as values. I want to sort it firstly by length, and if length of the strings is the same, i want to sort it alphabetic. 
I wrote those code :

```
String out = outMap.values().stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.length()).thenComparing()...)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

The problem is, when i am writing thenComparing, I couldn't use `e.length()` anymore. How can i fix it?

EDIT : `Map<Character, String>` . I want to sort the strings and make one string in output by concat all of them.

Comment: What are the types of `outMap`?

Comment: fix what? what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Map<Character, String>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
String out = outMap.values().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
                          .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
                    //OR  .thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: Alternatively, `(String e) -> e.length()`.

Comment: `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)
             .thenComparing(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);` just in case.