# How can I sort with multiple sort matches?

Tags: java, spring-boot, comparator

I want to sort my collection where SomeObject has a  name property. I want that property value "Foo" to be ranked first then "Bar" ranked second. Then sort alphabetically and then by the start date.

Currently, it is only working for "Foo" and the dates. I was wondering how can I include a second sort ranking here? So it's Foo > Bar > Alpha > Start Date

Code snippet:

```
List<SomeObject> sortedBaz = baz
    .stream()
    .sorted(compareBazStuff.thenComparing(compareBazStartDates))
    .collect(toList());

private static final String Foo = "Foo";
private static final String Bar = "Bar";

private static final Comparator<SomeObject> compareBazStuff= comparing(SomeObject::getName, ClassName::doComparison);

private static final Comparator<SomeObject> compareBazStartDates = comparing(SomeObject::getStartDate).reversed();

private static int doComparison(String stuff, String otherStuff) {
 if (Foo.equals(stuff) && !Foo.equals(otherStuff)) {
     return -1;
 }
 if (!Foo.equals(stuff) && Foo.equals(otherStuff)) {
     return 1;
 }
 return stuff.compareTo(otherStuff);
}
```

Comment: I think you're looking for "thenComparing()", see [How to use thenComparing in java stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796108/how-to-use-thencomparing-in-java-stream) or [Comparator.comparing(...) of a nested field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533338/comparator-comparing-of-a-nested-field) to see how they work.

Comment: @Scratte I can use thenComparing for alpha but what if I want to do a secondary sort. Like Foo, then Bar for Name match. Should I use a thenComparing with another method like the one above for Bar? Or is there a cleaner way?

Comment: You can chain how many thenComparing you need. If I understand your Question, then you have only someObjects, and they have 4 properties, foo, bar, alpha and startDate. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Just two properties (Name and StartDate) but I want to sort by Property Name Value : "Foo", Then "Bar." Then Alphabetically by Name (I mean), Then Start Date.

Comment: You post has two String objects. One is named Foo, the other named Bar. There is no property called Name. How do they fit into this? Can you show what the class really looks like?

Comment: There is this comparator: 

private static final Comparator<SomeObject> compareBazStuff= comparing(SomeObject::getName, ClassName::doComparison); There is a Name property on SomeObject, who's values can be "Foo", "Bar", "ABC", "Dog", etc.. whatever string. I want to sort the SomeObjects list where Name is "Foo" First, then Name is "Bar", then alphabetically by whatever string is left. Does that make sense?

Comment: He wants to sort on the same property multiple times. You can't do that with multiple then comparings, but what you could do is write a custom comparator that returns the ordering which handles foo and baz first, then probably use Strings comparator last.